# How do I group the results in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Project class like this :

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [ tasks : Tasks , users : User ]
    static belongsTo = User
    String name
    String toString() {
        this.name
    }
}
```

User class like this :

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [ project: Project ]
    Profile profile
    String username
    String password
    String toString() {
        this.username
    }
}
```

And Tasks class like this :

```
class Tasks {
    static belongsTo = [ user : User, project: Project ]
    boolean completed
    String toString(){
       this.title
    }
}
```

`User` will be having many `Project` and `Project` will be having many `Tasks`.

Now I need a way to query the DB to find, all the `Tasks` that are `completed` and that belongs to a `Project`. That is for example say that there are two projects, say `P1` and `P2`. In which `P1` has 4 completed `Tasks` and `P2` has 1 completed `Tasks`. My code need to return something like :

```
[P1:[t1,t2,t3,t4],P2:[t5]]
```

I know its easy to find all the `Tasks` that are completed, which will return like this :

```
[t1,t2,t3,t4,t5]
```

But I find it difficult to group them according to their `Project`.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` on Collection: [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) or [EXAMPLE](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps)

For example:

```
def completedTasks = Task.findAllByCompleted(true)
def compltedTasksByProject = compltedTasks.groupBy {it.project}
```

Should give you what you want.